# Simple image swap with fade on hover

Tags: jquery, image, hover

I'm looking for a simple way to swap an image on hover with cross fade. I have seen lots of solutions - but everything I have found seems bloated & complicated. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Img swap code I'm using:

```
$(function() {
$(".img-swap").hover(
    function() {
        this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
    },
        function() {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
    });
});
```

Is there a way to add fadeIn / fadeOut here? Or is this the wrong way to go about this? Everything I've tried doesn't seem to work! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The really simple solution is to have two images, which is needed if you're doing a cross fade, as both images will visible at the same time, and just fade one out and the other one in, like [**THIS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/xTw44/) ???

Comment: Thanks for your help - this seems to be the best solution. If you post as answer I will accept this. Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to help, added an answer with the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cross fade two images, both images will at some point be visible, so you'll need two images in the DOM. You could do it with just one image, but then you would have to fade the image out, swap the source, and fade it in, which is'nt really a cross fade.

```
<img src="image1.png" id="test" />
<img src="image2.png" id="test2" />​
```

JS:

```
$('#test').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
        $('#test2').fadeIn('slow');
});

$('#test2').css({left: $('#test').position().left, top: $('#test').position().top})
           .on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
        $('#test').fadeIn('slow');
});
​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/xTw44/)

Comment: Great thanks. The only thing I did differently was to remove `.css({left: $( '#test' ).position().left, top: $( '#test' ).position().top})` and instead in css add `#test2 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}`

Comment: Yeah, that works to, I just used the position trick to position the second image exactly the same as the first, but a wrapper and a little css would fix that as well, so not really a problem. Happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/asafoq/1/edit)**

```
  $(".img-swap").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){

    var mE = e.type=='mouseenter';
    var c = ['_on','_off'];
    this.src = this.src.replace( mE?c[1]:c[0] , mE?c[0]:c[1] );
    $(this).hide().stop().fadeTo(1000,1);

  });
```

Comment: This also works great, however it fades to white / background instead of other image, though perhaps I didn't make that clear in question. Thanks all the same.

Comment: @vonholmes yes... adeneo's answer is not only good cause it's the best way to fade-into, but also all your images will be loaded and there will be no jQuery image request and load time issue :) You're welcome

Answer (score 0):

use below code and also include the jquery.

```
 $("#one").hover(function(){$('#one').fadeOut(1000);$('#two').fadeIn(2000);}
);
 $('#one').fadeIn(2000);

<span id="one"><img serc="image1path"></span>
<span id="two" style="display:none"><img serc="image2path"></span>
```